# Deleting element from multidimensional-array based on value

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to delete the elements inside a multi-dimensional array based on value which is **StockNo**.

My array is like this:

```
Array[2]
 0: Object
        StockNo: "1"
        InvoiceNo: "1234"
        MaterialName: "MaterialName1"
        PONo: "1234"
        PRNo: "2124"
        Project: "ProjectName"
        Qty: "1"
        Remarks: "Test"
        Supplier: "SupplierName"
        TotalAmount: "23"
        Type: "2"
        Unit: "23"

  1: Object 
        StockNo: "2"      
        InvoiceNo: "1234"
        MaterialName: "MaterialName2"
        PONo: "1234"
        PRNo: "2124"
        Project: "ProjectName2"
        Qty: "1"
        Remarks: "Test"
        Supplier: "SupplierName"
        TotalAmount: "23"
        Type: "2"
        Unit: "23"
```

The logic is:

```
var StockNo = 1;
while(//find StockNo in the Multi-dimentional array ){
    if(//StockNo found){
       //remove element
    }
}
```

How can I do this in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KYLE GWAPO**

Try to Use array filter :

```
  var arrayOrig = [{ StockNo: "1",
                                InvoiceNo: "1234",
                                MaterialName: "MaterialName1",
                                PONo: "1234",
                                PRNo: "2124",
                                Project: "ProjectName",
                                Qty: "1",
                                Remarks: "Test",
                                Supplier: "SupplierName",
                                TotalAmount: "23",
                                Type: "2",
                                Unit: "23"},
                             {StockNo: "2",      
                                InvoiceNo: "1234",
                                MaterialName: "MaterialName2",
                                PONo: "1234",
                                PRNo: "2124",
                                Project: "ProjectName2",
                                Qty: "1",
                                Remarks: "Test",
                                Supplier: "SupplierName",
                                TotalAmount: "23",
                                Type: "2",
                                Unit: "23"}]
           console.log(arrayOrig);

           var filter_array = arrayOrig
                   .filter(function (el) {
                            alert(el.StockNo);
                            return el.StockNo !== "1";
                           });

            console.log(filter_array);
```

**KYLE GWAPO PERO JOKE RA**